# Raspberry Pi3 - Controlling 4 DC motors

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, rpi.gpio, pwm, dc-motor

I need to feed 4 DC motors of 5V on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B using PWM (Pulse Width Modulation).

Currently, I have the next components: 2 NPM transistors, 1 L293D integrated circuit, resistors (220 Ohms), wires, etc.

My question is, what is the correct way to feed the 4 motors with 4 GPIO pins?

I will appreciate any kind of help.

**circuit diagram** [image: circuit diagram]

Comment: All you need are two L293D.  Each contains the electronics needed to safely drive 2 DC motors.  Plenty of tutorials if you search.  I would check they can provide enough current for your motors.

Comment: Thanks @joan, so with 2 l293d i could feed 4 motors safely using 5V of Raspberry pi¿ i fear to burn my gpio if it is not enough

Comment: @joan as you can see in the diagram, i have already controlled 1 motor  with 1 NPN transistor, could i use 2 npm transistors instead of l293d? Thanks for your help

Comment: @joan using 2 l293d with Vmotor=9V works, nevertheless after some seconds running the motor stops... It seems that l293d are overheated. So it seems to be a bad solution